# "neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing" - NDSolver Problem

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation, subscript

I'm currently working on a simulation of *n* linked pendulums and I'm using the Euler-Lagrange Equations to solve the problem. As I compile this error appears several times:
**"ReplaceAll: {{}[[1,1]]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid \
dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing"**. Here's the chunk of code I got 'til this point:

```
VarVector := 
 Join[Table[Subscript[\[Theta], i - 1][t], {i, n + 1}], 
  Table[Subscript[\[Theta], i - 1]'[t], {i, n + 1}]]
InitConditions := 
 Prepend[Join[Table[Subscript[\[Theta], i][0] == \[Pi]*0.5, {i, n}], 
   Table[Subscript[\[Theta], i - 1]'[0] == 0, {i, n + 1}]], 
  Subscript[\[Theta], 0][0] == 0]
AllEqn = Join[AllEq[n], InitConditions];
solution := 
 NDSolve[AllEqn, VarVector, {t, 0, 25}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

I'm using n=5 and theta_0 as the position (resp. \theta'_0 speed) of the fixed point of the first pendulum. Help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange! A few comments. Please have a working example. For instance, include `n=5` in the code block. Most importantly, include the definition of `AllEq`. Once the question includes a working example, people can evaluate it to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: I suspect a problem with the statement `AllEqn = Join[AllEq[n], InitConditions];` because `AllEq[n]` is not defined. Can you edit your question and make this clear?